# Sequentially Continuous Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

I am slightly confused about the following example. Consider the sequence $x_n=1/n$. The $x_n$ converges to $0$. The function $f(x)=1/x$ is continuous on the interval $(0,1)$, and so it is also sequentially continuous. However, $f(x_n)=n$ clearly diverges. What am I missing here?

Comment: $x_n$ doesn’t converge within the space $X$. That is, a convergent limit must be in the set $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being sequentially continuous means that if $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of elements of $(0,1)$ which converges to an elment $a\in(0,1)$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=f(a)$. Since $\left(\frac1n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ does *not* converge to an element of $(0,1)$, there is no problem.